# show and hide animation image when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to show and hide the animation gif file when button is pressed in the home page.  Please if there a way like this let me know.

how to use curl up and curl down in the above question.

Comment: what do u want to show and hide?

Comment: want to show UIImageView

Comment: Because i want to use that button as "About" the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. Instead of using a `UIImageView`, use another `UIViewController`.
From your main `UIViewController`, create a `Modal Segue` to another `UIViewController`.

In the attributes inspector of your `segue` - set the animation to **Partial Curl**.

In that `UIViewController`, add your UIImageView with the GIF file - and a back button to dismiss the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside button action ,in this code viewcontroller is removed, and the "home" viewcontroller is added, with a pageflip like transition

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.base.view cache:YES];

[user.view removeFromSuperview];
[base.view addSubview:home.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIAnimation block, initially set the UIImageView frame to (0,480,320,480). So that it will be out of screen i.e it won't be visible then on button click change the Y coordinate to zero using animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

Comment: How does this address his Curl Up and Curl Down question ?